# ES6 import and npm packages

Tags: npm, import

Anyone got a link to documentation explaining exactly how ES6 import is supposed to work with npm packages (as opposed to javascript module files) ?

Also (and possibly related) a link to documentation on the use/significance of "module" as a top-level key in an npm package.json file ?

Eg. consider the following from [juggle/resize-observer](https://github.com/juggle/resize-observer) ;

**package.json**

```
{
...
"module": "lib/exports/resize-observer.js",
...
}
```

**consumer javascript file**

```
import { ResizeObserver } from '@juggle/resize-observer';
```

On the above import Chrome sends a request to the server for '@juggle/resize-observer' which is a directory..... so what happens next ? (I don't have a working instance of this and my server doesn't return anything yet as I don't know what it's supposed to / in what format ). Is this syntax only for use with some sort of build tool where it ultimately gets replaced with the actual file ?

I have looked at the npm site/googled and cannot find any relevant documentation.

**UPDATE** Still waiting for a link to relevant documentation (no relevant Google results at this time) but for anyone asking the same question: apparently you need your server to do "module resolution" . Alternatively you can use [Snowpack](https://github.com/pikapkg/snowpack) or a bundler eg. Webpack.

Comment: This is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66248026/how-can-i-publish-es6-classes-in-an-npm-package-and-import-them-into-another-ap/66248027#66248027

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently npm/node packages are not packaged with browsers in mind or based on any W3C/Web Modules standard specification.

See [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together.) for module resolution info.

So at present to use an npm package in a browser you must do one of the following

1. use a bundler like webpack
2. use [snowpack](https://github.com/pikapkg/snowpack)
3. use a CDN which resolves the module request
4. implement npm module resolution in your own server
5. Find the package entry point and use that in your ES6 import statement.
   However, if the package's json "main" property changes in a subsequent update you
   will need to update your code to reflect this.