# How can I publish ES6+ classes in an npm package and import them into another application

Tags: npm, ecmascript-6, import, export

I am writing a react application and want to reuse some components from another application, so I thought I could easily move the shared components into an npm package, but this turns out to be a minefield of combinations of syntax, most of which don't work.

For all of the non-working syntax variations I have tried, the run-time error message I get from react is "Expecting object or string but got undefined. Maybe you mixed up default and named exports".

Because this issue spans multiple technologies (React, ES5, ES6,Babel and Node.js) there seems to be no documentation that explains how to make all of these things work together.

The various ways that I have tried to write the shared component look like this:

```js
export default Component1 = (props) => {}
```

OR

```js
const Component1 = (props) => {}
export default Component1;
```

OR

```js
export Component1 = (props) => {}
```

OR

```js
const Component1 = (props) => {}
export Component1;
```

OR

```js
const Component1 = (props) => {}
export { Component1 };
```

OR

```js
const Component1 = (props) => {}
export default { Component1 };
```

The various ways that I tried to export this from the npm package in an `index.js` file look like this:

```js
export Component1 from './Component1';
export Component2 from './Component2';
```

OR

```js
export { Component1 } from './Component1';
export { Component2 } from './Component2';
```

OR

```js
import { Component1 } from './Component1';
import { Component2 } from './Component2';
export Component1;
export Component2;
```

OR

```js
import { Component1 } from './Component1';
import { Component2 } from './Component2';
export { Component1, Component2 };
```

OR

```js
import { Component1 } from './Component1';
import { Component2 } from './Component2';
export default { Component1, Component2 };
```

The various ways that I tried to import this shared component into my application look like this:

```js
import Component1 from 'my-shared-package';
```

OR

```js
import { Component1 } from 'my-shared-package';
```

As you can see the permutations really rack up, and all the permutations I tried so far result in the run-time error from React. Trying each permutation takes time because the package has be be built and published for each attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing all of the permutations above, I found only one that actually worked for me. To save everyone else from going through the same exercise, here is the version that works.

Note that every component must be in its own source file.

Let's say that Component1 has no dependencies. You should write it like this:

```js
const Component1 = (props) => { return (<div />); }

export default Component1;
```

Let's say that Component2 depends on Component1. It would be written like this:

```js
import Component1 from './Component1';

const Component2 = (props) => { return (<Component1 />); }

export default Component2;
```

Now we need to export these components by creating an `index.js` file that will be the entry point to the npm package. This file need to look like this:

```js
import Component1 from './Component1';
import Component2 from './Component2';

export { Component1, Component2 }
```

Now we need to use Babel to transpile these source files into ES5 syntax and publish the output to npm. You can see a working example of how to do this here: https://github.com/Bikeman868/react-svg-pie

To import these components into your application, you need to `npm install <package>`, then reference them in your source code like this:

```js
import { Component1, Component2 } from 'my-shared-package';
```

The important points to check are:

1. Have a separate source file for each component and export the component from that source file as the default export.
2. When importing these components within your npm package don't put `{ }` around it because this is only for named exports and we exported it as the default export.
3. In your `index.js` file you need to import the components as default imports (without the `{ }`) and export all of the components inside `{ }` and without the `default` keyword.
4. Within the application where you are using these components you must enclose them in `{ }` for them to work because they were exported from the npm package as named exports.

That's it. Simple when you know how!